# Ancient Kext, Signing issues

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, codesign, kernel-extension

I have a ancient kext (last supported with 10.7.5). It works when disabling SIP and such.
The question I'm having, is if you could sign that ancient text? I already tried]`codesign -s "Developer ID Application:" --verbose Downloads/private/tmp/InstallerTemp/M-AudioFireWireBeBoB.kext/`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much detail. Does signing fail? If it succeeds, what does `kextutil path/to/M-AudioFireWireBeBoB.kext` say?

A few things I can think of that could be causing problems:

- I don't think codesigning works for kexts with a 32-bit slice. So if it's a universal 32/64-bit kext (or if it still has a PPC slice ), extract the x86-64 binary using `lipo` and use only that instead.
- The signing certificate must have the special kext signing feature associated with it. Apple only grants that upon special request, a regular Developer ID Application certificate is not sufficient for kexts.
- On macOS 10.14.5+ and 10.15, the kext must additionally be notarised. Create a zipfile of the kext, and upload it to Apple using `xcrun altool --notarize-app`. Once approved, you can staple the notarisation to the kext using `xcrun stapler staple path/to/your.kext`. See Apple's documentation on notarisation and the output of `xcrun altool --help` for details.

Comment: Kextutil outputs this: `Kext with invalid signature (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd603524d00 [0x7fff92875670]> { URL = "file:///Library/Extensions/M-AudioFireWireBeBoB.kext/", ID = "com.m-audio.driver.firewire" }
Code Signing Failure: not code signed`

Comment: And yes, it still has a PPC slice :D

Comment: I think I cannot notarise it with apple, because I don't have any source code and the manufacturer isn't going to give it to me..

Comment: When I run ` xcrun altool --notarize-app -u USER -p PASS -f M-AudioFireWireBeBoB.kext.zip --primary-bundle-id M-AudioFireWireBeBoB` I get `Error: Unable to validate your application. We are unable to create an authentication session.`

Comment: And when I try and use lipo it just gives me `can't map input file: M-AudioFireWireBeBoB.kext (Invalid argument)`

Comment: I don't have any clues about kexts btw. I only know how to use them xD Thank you for your help

Comment: @NiklasArnitz Do you have access to a Developer ID Application + Kext signing certificate? Without this, any further advice is going to be pointless.

Comment: I have access to a full-paid Developer Account.

Comment: @NiklasArnitz Has this account successfully applied for a kext signing certificate? When issuing a Developer ID Certificate, the developer centre will specifically mention kexts if so.

Comment: I did just apply. What should I do, if I get accepted?